# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException al ejecutar método update

Tags: laravel

Esta es la entidad **Speciality**:

```
class Speciality extends Model
   {
//
  protected $fillable = ['name','description'];

public function doctor(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Doctor');
}

public function getName(){
  return $this->name;
}
public function getDescription(){
  return $this->description;
}
    }
```

Y los siguientes métodos de su controlador:

**SpecialityController-edit**

```
public function edit( Speciality $speciality)
{
  return view('specialities/edit')->with('speciality', $speciality);

}
```

**SpecialityController-update**

```
public function update(Request $request, Speciality $speciality)
{
    //
    $this->validate($request,[
      'name' => 'required|max:300',
      'description' => 'required|max:500'
    ]);

    $speciality->fill($request->all());
    $speciality->save();

    return Redirect::to('specialities');



}
```

Y además, **edit.blade de Speciality**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
    @include('layouts.menu')
    @section('content')
         <form action="updateSpeciality" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
          <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

               <div class="form-group col-md-2" >
               <label for="exampleInputName1">Editar nombre</label>
                <input name=name  class="form-control" 
                  id="exampleInputName1"  >



                         </div>
                     <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                    <label for="exampleInputDescription1">Editar 
                     descripción</label>
                     <input name="description" class="form-control" 
                      id="exampleInputDescription1" >
                       </div>


                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </form>
                        @endsection
```

Y sus rutas definidas:

```
Route::get('specialities', 'SpecialityController@index');
Route::get('createSpeciality', 'SpecialityController@create');
Route::post('storeSpeciality', 'SpecialityController@store');
Route::get('editSpeciality', 'SpecialityController@edit');
Route::post('updateSpeciality', 'SpecialityController@update');
```

Al intentar actualizar una Speciality, se muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desconozco por qué se esta produciendo. Intenté solucionarlo mediante la línea `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">`
ya que leí que podía ser ese el problema, mas se sigue produciendo este error. ¿Es quizás error del método update del controlador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `method` enviado desde el formulario y el definido en la ruta correspondiente han de ser el mismo.
Al estar haciendo un `update` hay que usar PUT por lo que la ruta debería ser así:

```
Route::put('updateSpeciality', 'SpecialityController@update');
```

En el formulario has de enviar PUT. Por lo tanto tu formulario debería quedar así:

```
<form action="updateSpeciality" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="exampleInputName1">Editar nombre</label>
        <input name=name class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
        <label for="exampleInputDescription1">Editar descripción</label>
        <input name="description" class="form-control" id="exampleInputDescription1">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
</form>
```